# How to customize wordpress dashboard logo?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone help me please figure out how to modify this image in a wordpress plugin?

[image]

I'm not trying to make it so it's a user set option, just different than the default with a pre-defined logo I have selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looked at the HTML you would have seen it is a [sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).
So it can be overrulled with your own css sprite.

To add css to the wp-admin use [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), also look at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)
questions? ask.

Answer (score 0):

Change your dashboard logo with this code:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_logo');

function my_custom_logo() {
echo '
<style type="text/css">
#header-logo { background-image: url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/custom-logo.gif) !important; }
</style>
';
}
```